# Replacing new line character with html <br /> tag in Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

I'm trying to `.gsub` a newline character with an HTML tag 
 but it returns the Unicode instead of the actual tag.

My code looks something like this:

```rb
def replace
  string.gsub(/\R+/, '<br />')
end

"Hello\nWorld".gsub(/\R+/, '<br />')
```

Should be expecting something similar to

`Hello<br />World`

but I'm getting

`Hello\u003cbr /\u003eWorld`

instead.

Comment: You are setting the text field value with the gsub result, you should set the HTML value. Something like that. Show the code.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. `> "Hello\nWorld".gsub(/\R+/, '<br />') # => "Hello<br />World"`

Comment: What encoding do you have set? This works for me as well, so it could be a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
<%= @the_string.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Please add description around your answer, so that it will helpful for future users.

Comment: Code only answers are considered low-quality posts. Please add some explanation for your code